# How can I view putty log files with color in Notepad++ or other text editors?

Tags: notepad++, putty, colors, logging, text-editors

I have a putty log file that contains color markup, e.g.:

```
[0m[33mSome colored error text
[35mSome more colored error text
[0mSome stuff
```

Is there a way to easily view these log files in color? Bonus points for solutions that:

- Use notepad++
- Don't display the color sequence (e.g. [35m) , and instead just colors the text

Comment: See [Text editor/viewer with ANSI codes rendering support for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2271785/850848) (ironically the question is on SO, where I've asked you to move your question to SU. But it's an old question from times the SU was only starting).

Answer (score 6):

You can install MINGW64 (Cygwin should also works) and run:

`less -R your_putty_logfile.log`

Notice `-R` option. For me it works pretty fine.

Comment: Can't believe this actually worked in Windows 11 **cmd** with cygwin installed.

Answer (score 3):

Recently, someone created a Python script by which to enable ASCII color coding in NotePad++.

https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/8078

The actual script is at: https://github.com/Ekopalypse/NppPythonScripts/blob/master/npp/error_list_lexer_support.py

And for easier use, I've copied it below:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
    Makes the builtin errorlist lexer available for npp.
    
    To toggle the escape characters on/off one can
    create another script with these two lines of code.
    
    error_list_lexer.show_escape_chars = not error_list_lexer.show_escape_chars
    editor.styleSetVisible(error_list_lexer.SCE_ERR_ESCSEQ, error_list_lexer.show_escape_chars)
'''

from Npp import notepad, editor, NOTIFICATION


class ErrorListLexer:

    def __init__(self):
        '''
            Initialize the class, should be called only once.
        '''

        # **************** configuration area ****************
        # files with these extensions and a null lexer,
        # aka normal text, assigned do get handled
        self.known_extensions = ['log', 'txt']
        #
        self.show_escape_chars = False
        self.separate_path_and_line_number = '0'
        self.interpret_escape_sequences = '1'
        # ****************************************************
        
        self.SCE_ERR_DEFAULT =0
        self.SCE_ERR_PYTHON =1
        self.SCE_ERR_GCC =2
        self.SCE_ERR_MS =3
        self.SCE_ERR_CMD =4
        self.SCE_ERR_BORLAND =5
        self.SCE_ERR_PERL =6
        self.SCE_ERR_NET =7
        self.SCE_ERR_LUA =8
        self.SCE_ERR_CTAG =9
        self.SCE_ERR_DIFF_CHANGED = 10
        self.SCE_ERR_DIFF_ADDITION = 11
        self.SCE_ERR_DIFF_DELETION = 12
        self.SCE_ERR_DIFF_MESSAGE = 13
        self.SCE_ERR_PHP = 14
        self.SCE_ERR_ELF = 15
        self.SCE_ERR_IFC = 16
        self.SCE_ERR_IFORT = 17
        self.SCE_ERR_ABSF = 18
        self.SCE_ERR_TIDY = 19
        self.SCE_ERR_JAVA_STACK = 20
        self.SCE_ERR_VALUE = 21
        self.SCE_ERR_GCC_INCLUDED_FROM = 22
        self.SCE_ERR_ESCSEQ = 23
        self.SCE_ERR_ESCSEQ_UNKNOWN = 24
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_BLACK = 40
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_RED = 41
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_GREEN = 42
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_BROWN = 43
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_BLUE = 44
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_MAGENTA = 45
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_CYAN = 46
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_GRAY = 47
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_DARK_GRAY = 48
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_RED = 49
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_GREEN = 50
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_YELLOW = 51
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_BLUE = 52
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_MAGENTA = 53
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_CYAN = 54
        self.SCE_ERR_ES_WHITE = 55

        notepad.callback(self.on_langchanged, [NOTIFICATION.LANGCHANGED])
        notepad.callback(self.on_bufferactivated, [NOTIFICATION.BUFFERACTIVATED])


    def init_lexer(self):
        '''
            Initializes the lexer and its properties
            Args:
                None
            Returns:
                None
        '''
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_DEFAULT, notepad.getEditorDefaultForegroundColor())
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_PYTHON, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_GCC, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_MS, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_CMD, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_BORLAND, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_PERL, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_NET, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_LUA, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_CTAG, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_DIFF_CHANGED, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_DIFF_ADDITION, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_DIFF_DELETION, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_DIFF_MESSAGE, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_PHP, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ELF, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_IFC, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_IFORT, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ABSF, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_TIDY, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_JAVA_STACK, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_VALUE, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_GCC_INCLUDED_FROM, (255,0,0))

        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ESCSEQ, (30,30,30))
        editor.styleSetVisible(self.SCE_ERR_ESCSEQ, self.show_escape_chars)
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ESCSEQ_UNKNOWN, (255,255,120))
        editor.styleSetVisible(self.SCE_ERR_ESCSEQ_UNKNOWN, self.show_escape_chars)

        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_BLACK, (0,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_RED, (255,0,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_GREEN, (0,255,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_BROWN, (150,75,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_BLUE, (0,0,255))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_MAGENTA, (255,200,255))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_CYAN, (255,200,100))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_GRAY, (128,128,128))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_DARK_GRAY, (255,200,100))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_RED, (170, 1, 20))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_GREEN, (255,200,100))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_YELLOW, (255,255,0))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_BLUE, (9,84,190))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_MAGENTA, (229,8,194))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_BRIGHT_CYAN, (27,244,207))
        editor.styleSetFore(self.SCE_ERR_ES_WHITE, (255,255,255))

        editor.setLexer(10)
        # ordering is important
        editor.setProperty('lexer.errorlist.value.separate', self.separate_path_and_line_number)
        editor.setProperty('lexer.errorlist.escape.sequences', self.interpret_escape_sequences)


    def check_lexers(self):
        '''
            Checks if the current document is of interest.
            Args:
                None
            Returns:
                None
        '''

        has_no_lexer_assigned = editor.getLexerLanguage() == 'null'
        _, _, file_extension = notepad.getCurrentFilename().rpartition('.')
        if has_no_lexer_assigned and file_extension in self.known_extensions:
            self.init_lexer()


    def on_bufferactivated(self, args):
        '''
            Callback which gets called every time one switches a document.
            Triggers the check if the document is of interest.
            Args:
                provided by notepad object but none are of interest
            Returns:
                None
        '''
        self.check_lexers()


    def on_langchanged(self, args):
        '''
            Callback gets called every time one uses the Language menu to set a lexer
            Triggers the check if the document is of interest
            Args:
                provided by notepad object but none are of interest
            Returns:
                None
        '''
        self.check_lexers()


    def main(self):
        '''
            Main function entry point.
            Simulates the buffer_activated event to enforce 
            detection of current document and potential styling.
            Args:
                None
            Returns:
                None
        '''
        self.on_bufferactivated(None)


error_list_lexer = ErrorListLexer()
error_list_lexer.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replay the log file in TeraTerm.
File -> New Connection -> TCPI/IP:  /R="C:\somelofile.log"

B.T.W
In TeraTerm you can log escape commands when log to binary file format.